# I just bought a panasonic HC-VX981K 4K camera and wondering which is my best format to shoot in?

Tags: camcorder, 4k, panasonic

I just bought my panasonic HC-VX981K and was wondering which is the best format for just recording perfect video, it states that higher bitrate in 4K MP4 format but I'm hearing AVCHD progressive is best , I don't know, I'm needing help here

Comment: First think about what film/project you want to do, then what requirements you have and check what format fulfills your requirements best. There is no such thing as perfect video or a universally best format. It always depends on the project. This means without specific details we cannot help you. Also read the manual, they describe when each of the available formats is suitable.

Comment: @matt - Oh ok , Thank you sir , basically I'm just creating short videos of my son , with the camcorder , I was just uncertain about which format for best quality video to just playback thru HDMI to FHD TV to watch, no special editing ....!

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with AVCHD, but it often led to corrupted files. It is quite sensitive to SD card quality, stability of the power, etc.

I ended up recording at FHD 50p.  FHD because the 4K isn't really good enough to call it 4K - the result, when played on a 4K screen, is rather blurry and grainy, as if the camera upscaled. 50p because anything below is almost unusable.

Update: I have digged a bit deeper. And it seems that AVCHD is there basically only for compatibility with Apple, somehow. AVCHD also records using the h264 codec. But the bitrate for AVCHD is way lower than for MP4 50p. Which means: Do not record to AVCHD if you do not have any technical reason for it (processing your videos on uncompatible Apple products).

Also, if it's for indoor family videos, I recommend not to use HDR, it just makes everything foggy. Better pay attention to where the light comes from.